Blacklist the "homework" tag
homework should be blacklisted. 
We had the discussion once before about what to do about homework. There it was agreed that homework questions are find but we didn't like meta tags like homework. I believe the tag was cleared and deleted.
The tag found its way back. We talked about it further and the possibility of blacklisting it came up.

AFAIK this is the correct way to request a blacklist. We'll see what happens.

The first thing to do is to make sure that no questions have just the homework tag. When you've done that, ping me and I'll see what I can do.

@JonEricson okay. I wasn't sure if you all could do that or not.

@JonEricson done.

The homework tag is now blacklisted and there are (and will always be) 0 questions with this tag. 

Did something happen to the blacklist? http://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/20706/revisions

Checking the answers to the questions you’ve linked to, I noticed most has already been said. Therefore, I’ll keep it short and simple:
If there’s an option to blacklist it, I’m all for it.
“Good” questions, which emerge from homework or exam preparations, will surely be able to make their way into Crypto.SE without that tag. And while blacklisting homework seems a bit drastic at first, it does make sense because otherwise, new users are bound to try to recreate that tag again, and again, and…
